# Odd Reputation change with no trail

Tags: support, reputation

I had a reputation change today by which I lost 42 reputation points.  The only problem is I can't find any trail as to what exactly has happened.  I can probably guess which questions were removed but I can't be sure.

Is there any way to find that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reputation tab](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/41542/karlson?tab=reputation) on your profile should tell you all you need to know.

However, you will have to check through the entire list to be sure. A quick look shows that Jan 20th might be one of the occasions where posts were deleted.

Comment: Ok.  Got it.  It seems that the color scheme as displayed by Chrome doesn't show the expansion arrow, which is a different question altogether.

Comment: Yeah I came with this exact same question, I noticed I had lost over 200 points... and yep, -229 points on October 6 2011. Awesome?

Comment: I just came with the same question (glad I searched before asking). I dropped by something like 150points without seeing anything. And now I just noticed that a llllooonnnggg time back some questions were deleted. I'm assuming this is related to the [upcoming history changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) as well, maybe? I mean, the log shows these deleted questions in **November** and the points were lost just within the last 3 days, isn't that a bit odd?

Comment: @haylem - you "lost" those points (in reality it's more like you never had them) back in November when the question was deleted. It's just that the reported reputation didn't use to keep up with deletions - it does now.